# Section number in endnotes with babel and book class (follow-up)

Tags: babel, books, endnotes

This is a follow-up question to this post: [Section number in endnotes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/386318/section-number-in-endnotes/386336?noredirect=1#comment957699_386336)

I am using the endnotes package to list all notes at the end of a document. I'd like for the section header (notes) to also include the section number just as any other section. 
Users crixstox and Marijn both posted solutions that worked. Here's the one that crixstox posted:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{endnotes}
% Taken from endnotes.sty and changed \section*{ to \section{
\makeatletter
\def\enoteheading{\section{\notesname
\@mkboth{\MakeUppercase{\notesname}}{\MakeUppercase{\notesname}}}%
\mbox{}\par\vskip-\baselineskip}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\section{Some section}
bla bla bla\endnote{Some note}.
\endnote{Another note.} \endnote{A third note.}
\theendnotes
\end{document}
```

However, using the MWE with the book class together with babel will generate a plethora of illegal parameter errors. I'd of course like to know how to solve the concrete problem  - Getting a section number to my endnotes section, but I'm also curious as to what causes this fix together with babel and the book class to crash. It works fine alone with either babel or the book class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A numbered `\section` (unlike `\section*`) sets the header information for `book` using marking commands (such as `\markright`,`\markboth`,`\@mkboth`). These commands are redefined by `babel`. In `endnotes` the header mark is inside the section title. This combined leads to an error *somewhere*.

A possible solution is to define the mark below the section title:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{endnotes}
\makeatletter
\def\enoteheading{\section{\notesname}% added }
 \@mkboth{\MakeUppercase{\notesname}}{\MakeUppercase{\notesname}}% removed }
   \mbox{}\par\vskip-\baselineskip}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\section{Some section}
 bla bla bla\endnote{Some note}.
\theendnotes
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Note the `0.1`,`0.2` because there is no `\chapter` in the document.

Disclaimer: I don't know why the `@mkboth` was in the section title - something may break if it is moved out.